# Data Document Other than Data Dictionary for Project Stakeholders?

Tags: documentation, dataflow

I'm searching for some sort of document template or guidelines to produce a document that describes data flow, high level data field definitions, data ownership (who produces the master data), etc.

Not really a data dictionary but something intended for business users (non-techie) who are stakeholders in the project.

Anyone know of any such template/document style or will I need to define some sort of custom document to fulfil this need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "4+1 View Model".

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wireless/library/wi-arch11/

See http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~gregor/teaching/papers/4+1view-architecture.pdf

The point is to write from a user's perspective.

- Use Cases.
- Business Entities.  Not Tables.  Real Entities.  In the Real World.
- Processes.  Not Programs.  Real Processes that Real People Really Do.
- Physical View.  Computers and Disks and stuff.  This is more of an appendix than anything else when you're addressing Users and Requirements.  Later, you can elaborate this into technical details.
- Development View.  None of the user's business.  A part of the total package, but not relevant for high-level discussions with users.